# While loop in python not continuing even with correct input

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

While **msg loop** does not work even with value entered are 1 or 2, it always gives "wrong option", it should loop in all other inputs *except 1 or 2* and should go into **else** part where **if** statement should be executed. Need to implement *same loop* for password i.e instead of breaking it should loop correctly.

```
    import pyautogui
    import time
    from getpass import getpass
    import sys
            
    try:
    
            print("Note: password remains invisible while you type.")
    
            password = getpass(prompt='Type the Password and hit enter: ')
            if password == "12345":
                    msg = 0
                    while msg == 0:
                        print("\nSelect Option:")
                        print("1) You have a text file (words.txt) in the same folder as software.")
                        print("2) You want to type your message.\n")
                        msg = input("Enter the option no: ")
                        if msg != "1" or "2":
                            print("wrong option")
                            msg = 0    
                    else:
                        msg = msg
                        if msg == "1":
                                print("Click the message box, waiting for 5 seconds...")
                                time.sleep(1)
                                count = 5
                                while(count != 0):
                                        print(count)
                                        time.sleep(1)
                                        count -= 1
                                print("Fire!!!")
                                # from file
                                f = open("words.txt", 'r')
                                fd = f.read().splitlines()
                                for word in fd:
                                        pyautogui.typewrite(word)
                                        pyautogui.press("enter")
                                        #time.sleep(2)
                                print("DONE")
                        elif msg == "2":
                                msg = input("Enter the message: ")
                                n = input("How many times ?: ")
                                print("Click the message box, waiting for 5 seconds...")
                                time.sleep(1)
                                count = 5
                                while(count != 0):
                                        print(count)
                                        time.sleep(1)
                                        count -= 1
    
                                print("Fire in the hole!!!")
    
                                for i in range(0,int(n)):
                                        pyautogui.typewrite(msg + '\n')
                                        #time.sleep(2)
                                print("DONE")
                        else:
                                print("You entered Incorrect option.")
            else:
                    print("You must have valid pin to use the software.")
    except:
      sys.exit(1) # exiing with a non zero value is better for returning from an error
```

Comment: Needs to be re-written to `msg != 1 or msg != 2`.

Comment: try `if msg !="1" and msg !="2":`

Answer (score 0):

*while loop* is fixed using **msg !="1" *and* msg !="2"** thanks to drbwts and *password implementation* done in the code using stackoverflow search:

```
import pyautogui
import time
from getpass import getpass
import sys
    
    
    try:
            print("Note: password remains invisible while you type.")
    
            login = 1
            while login == 1:
                print("Enter the username and password \n")
                username = input("Username: ")
                password = getpass(prompt='Type the Password and hit enter: ')
                if password !=  "password" or username != "admin":
                    print("\nWrong username or password... \nTry Again...")
                    login = 1
                else:
                    login = -1
    
            while login == -1:
    
                    msg = 0
                    while msg == 0:
                        print("\nSelect Option:")
                        print("1) Extract text from (words.txt) in the same folder as software.")
                        print("2) Type your message.\n")
                        msg = input("Enter the option no or type quit: ")
                        if msg == "quit":
                            exit()
                        elif msg !="1" and msg !="2":
                            print("Invalid Option")
                            msg = 0
                    else:
                        msg = msg
                        if msg == "1":
                                print("Click the message box, waiting for 5 seconds...")
                                time.sleep(1)
                                count = 5
                                while(count != 0):
                                        print(count)
                                        time.sleep(1)
                                        count -= 1
                                print("Sending!")
                                # from file
                                f = open("words.txt", 'r')
                                fd = f.read().splitlines()
                                for word in fd:
                                        pyautogui.typewrite(word)
                                        pyautogui.press("enter")
                                        time.sleep(2)
                                print("DONE")
    
                        elif msg == "2":
                            msg = input("Enter the message: ")
                            while True:
                                    try:
                                        n = int(input("How many times ?: "))
                                        break
                                    except:
                                        print("enter a number!")
                            print("Click the message box, waiting for 5 seconds...")
                            time.sleep(1)
                            count = 5
                            while(count != 0):
                                print(count)
                                time.sleep(1)
                                count -= 1
    
                            print("Sending!")
    
                            for i in range(0,int(n)):
                                pyautogui.typewrite(msg + '\n')
                                time.sleep(2)
                            print("DONE")
                        else:
                                pass
            login = -1
    
    except:
        sys.exit(1)
```